# Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an error when running my code.

**Error message:**

> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   mvc-dispatcher threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'tipoSanguineoController': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   br.inf.datus.ifisio.service.TipoSanguineoService
>   br.inf.datus.ifisio.controller.TipoSanguineoController.tipoSanguineoService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'tipoSanguineoServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [D:\projetos\ifisio\target\ifisio\WEB-INF\classes\br\inf\datus\ifisio\service\TipoSanguineoServiceImpl.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [br.inf.datus.ifisio.service.TipoSanguineoServiceImpl]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   br.inf.datus.ifisio.service.TipoSanguineoServiceImpl.()
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   br.inf.datus.ifisio.service.TipoSanguineoService
>   br.inf.datus.ifisio.controller.TipoSanguineoController.tipoSanguineoService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'tipoSanguineoServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [D:\projetos\ifisio\target\ifisio\WEB-INF\classes\br\inf\datus\ifisio\service\TipoSanguineoServiceImpl.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [br.inf.datus.ifisio.service.TipoSanguineoServiceImpl]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   br.inf.datus.ifisio.service.TipoSanguineoServiceImpl.()
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

and my files:

**web.xml**:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>x</display-name>

<servlet>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="br.inf.datus.ifisio"/>

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <!-- Database properties -->
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

  <!-- Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

  <!--Prevent browsers from caching contents except the static resources content-->
  <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
      <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>
    <mvc:interceptor>
      <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
      <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/**"/>
      <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
      </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
  </mvc:interceptors>

  <!-- View Resolver -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- DataSource -->
  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>

    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${conn.acquireIncrement}"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${conn.minPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${conn.maxPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${conn.maxIdleTime}"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.entity"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Transaction -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**GenericDaoImpl**:

```
    package br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.dao.GenericDao;

@Repository
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, K extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, K> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Class<? extends E> daoType;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDaoImpl() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        daoType = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E entity) {
        currentSession().save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E findById(K key) {
        return (E) currentSession().get(daoType, key);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<E> getAll() {
        return currentSession().createCriteria(daoType).list();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(E entity) {
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E entity) {
        currentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(E entity) {
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }  
}
```

**GenericServiceImpl**:

```
    package br.inf.datus.ifisio.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.dao.GenericDao;

@Service
public abstract class GenericServiceImpl<E, K> implements GenericService<E, K> {

    private GenericDao<E, K> genericDao;

    public GenericServiceImpl(GenericDao<E,K> genericDao) {
        this.genericDao=genericDao;
    }

    public GenericServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void add(E entity) {
        genericDao.add(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
    public E findById(K id) {
        return genericDao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
    public List<E> getAll() {
        return genericDao.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void remove(E entity) {
        genericDao.remove(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void saveOrUpdate(E entity) {
        genericDao.saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void update(E entity) {
        genericDao.update(entity);
    }
}
```

**TipoSanguineoDaoImpl**:

```
package br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.dao;

import br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.entity.TipoSanguineo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class TipoSanguineoDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<TipoSanguineo, Long> implements TipoSanguineoDao {

}
```

**TipoSanguineoServiceImpl**:

```
package br.inf.datus.ifisio.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.dao.GenericDao;
import br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.dao.TipoSanguineoDao;
import br.inf.datus.ifisio.persistence.entity.TipoSanguineo;

@Service
public class TipoSanguineoServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<TipoSanguineo, Long> implements TipoSanguineoService {

    @Autowired
    private final TipoSanguineoDao tipoSanguineoDao;

    public TipoSanguineoServiceImpl(@Qualifier("tipoSanguineoDaoImpl") GenericDao<TipoSanguineo, Long> genericDao) {
        super(genericDao);
        this.tipoSanguineoDao = (TipoSanguineoDao) genericDao;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do constructor based dependency injection..
Below change in TipoSanguineoServiceImpl should correct your problem.

```
@Autowired
public TipoSanguineoServiceImpl(@Qualifier("tipoSanguineoDaoImpl") GenericDao<TipoSanguineo, Long> genericDao) {
            super(genericDao);
            this.tipoSanguineoDao = (TipoSanguineoDao) genericDao;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is there in the stack trace:

`Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [br.inf.datus.ifisio.service.TipoSanguineoServiceImpl]: No default constructor found;`

You have specified field injection in that class (`@Autowired` annotation on field `tipoSanguineoDao`) but you provided no default (no-argument) constructor. It appears that you want constructor injection (evidenced by the fact that you have a `@Qualifier` annotation on the constructor argument), but that conflicts with field injection.

Move the `@Autowired` annotation to the constructor.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers so that proper credit is given and others who read it know what the solution was.